# Telegram: How can I see who installed my sticker pack?

Tags: telegram

I created a sticker pack and via @stickers bot I am able to see some statistics including the number of installations of my sticker pack.

Is there a way to obtain a list of users who did install the stickerpack?

Answer (score 9):

You can write a `/packstats` command to **@stickers**, than choose the package you are interested in and it will send you some statistics: usage, installed and removed for today, yesterday and in total.

Answer (score 1):

Since Telegram protect user's privacy, there is **no way** to track this stats of stickers pack for now.

The only thing you can do is create a sticker contains your username, and wait user to say thanks to you :)

Comment: This is a nice idea! :]